# Django model fields. Custom field value setter

Tags: python, django

Is there any way to do in django custom property setter like this?

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    myfield = models.CharField(length = 250)

    @myfield.setter
    def set_password(self, value):
       self.password = encrypt(value)
```

Comment: this article by James Benett gives you a good idea on howto http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/aug/18/django-tips-using-properties-models-and-managers/

Comment: related/ dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898711/django-model-fields-getter-setter#11108157

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django model fields getter / setter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898711/django-model-fields-getter-setter)

Answer (score 1):

You will really *set* the value on saving the model, so it's better to override `save()` method (ot use `pre_save` signal).

Comment: Yes, I know. But I'm interested in properties only.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with a method?

```
instance.set_password('my_pw')
```

You can use `@property` to define setters:
http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property

```
### Pasted from docs

class C(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = None

    @property
    def x(self):
        """I'm the 'x' property."""
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self._x = value

    @x.deleter
    def x(self):
        del self._x
```

Comment: Sorry, but it's about pure class properties. Not about django models.

Comment: I suppose you could have a different property. But awesome idea. +1! Let me know if you find a solution.