# What is the proper way of creating a setter for non-property model field

Tags: django, django-models, setter

I want to define a `setter` function for a Django model field in order to validate the input and immediately raise a error if value is not valid.

I don't think that [doing the validation in `save()` or `pre_save()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7913108/django-model-fields-custom-field-value-setter) is a feasible solution for my problem because of things beyond my control.

Also changing the field into a property and use plain `field.getter` and `field.setter` are not feasible as this will break `.filter()`, `.exclude()` etc on the field, plus it will *require a scheme change* even if I changed `field` to `_field` and overrode the manager.

So, am I forced to override `__setattr__` or is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this django ticket:

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/3148

Also, see here for discussion:

[Django model fields getter / setter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898711/django-model-fields-getter-setter)

And this blog post:

http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/aug/18/django-tips-using-properties-models-and-managers/

Also note there is the option of using a custom manager that translates your `filter` `kwargs` for you, and using `_name` for fields, and making your own `@name.setter` `@name.getter` etc.

Comment: Instead of only providing links it would be useful if you summarise the idea behind each one in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could subclass the Field and override `to_python`.

```
class UnforgivingCharField(CharField):
    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase

    def to_python(self, value):
        if not passes_my_test(value):
            raise Hell()
        return super(UnforgivingCharField, self).to_python(value)
```

This is used when the value is set and also during `get_prep_value`, etc., so it will catch invalid values when filtering.

More on this [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/#the-subfieldbase-metaclass). Note the line at the bottom of the linked section that tells us `to_python` will be called.

Edit:  Just in case you happen to be using [South](http://south.areacode.org/), you will need to add some [introspection rules](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/customfields.html) if you implement custom model fields.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just define a function that provides the proper functionality and raises the correct error?

```
class YourModel(models.Model):

   def add_your_value(self, value):
       # check if value is correct
       # raise exception if it isn't
       # set correct property
```

Comment: Yes I can, but that does not stop other people from doing `mymodelinstance.is_this_true_or_false = "banana"`