# Can I call the assignment operator of my base class in Python?

Tags: python, django, inheritance, python-3.x, django-models

Django's `ImageField` lets me store a file object in it using a normal assignment.

```
from urllib import request
from django.db import models
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

class Customer(models.Model):
    logo = models.ImageField()

customer.logo = ContentFile(request.urlopen(url), 'image.png')
```

Now I want to inherit a custom field type from `ImageField`. It takes an URL as a plain string instead of a file object for assignment. Internally, it should fetch the image and assign it to it's base class, right as in the manual example above.

```
from django.db import models

class UrlImageField(models.ImageField):
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        super() = ContentFile(urllib.request.urlopen(value), 'image.png')
```

Therefore, I need to call the assignment operator on the `ImageField` base class. How can I do that in Python?

Comment: So what you want is create a field that fetches a remote URL and saves it as an ImageField, right?

Comment: What makes you think that Django is doing anything fancy with the assignment (hint: it isn't)? `image` is simply a name that first refers to the object created by `models.ImageField()`, then refers to the object created by `ContentFile`. That's all.

Comment: @chepner How does the `ContentFile` get stored in the database then? It though I would need a `ImageField` instance for this.

Comment: I'm not sure, but presumably it would work even if you did not assign the results of either command to `image`. My guess is that Django maintains some hidden references that are used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to (and *cannot*) overload assignment, but you simply want to extend the `ImageField` descriptor.
Descriptors are explained in the [Descriptor HowTo Guide](https://docs.python.org/3.4/howto/descriptor.html) in depth. You should also take a look at: [Understanding __get__ and __set__ and Python descriptors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798835/understanding-get-and-set-and-python-descriptors)

The essentials are that they define `__set__` and `__get__` methods that control the *attribute access*. These methods are just normal methods, so you'll have to extend them exactly as normal methods:

```
from django.db import models

class UrlImageField(models.ImageField):
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        super().__set__(instance, ContentFile(urllib.request.urlopen(value), 'image.png'))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, think I understand this now. However, it still [doesn't quite work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24957820/how-to-derive-a-custom-field-from-djangos-imagefield). Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 2):

The assignment operator cannot be overloaded.

Comment: How do they do that with Django's `ImageField` then?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by that? If I'm not mistaken, you're looking to overload the `=` python operator. That operator is intrinsic to the language and cannot be overloaded.

Comment: @danijar Note that `x = something` is *different* from `x.attribute = something`.  The first one **cannot** be overloaded, the latter can, in several ways. Also code inside classes is special, because you have some control over it using metaclasses (at least in python3.4+), while other code doesn't give that control.

Comment: In fact, `=` is not an operator; it is part of the assignment statement which is defined by the Python grammar, and is no more modifiable than an `if` statement.

Comment: @AshishKasturia Right, I though that `ImageField` would have to overload the `=` operator to make it possible to assign a `ContentFile` to it. Since that is not true, can you explain how this assignment works then? Are the two types related somehow?

Comment: The field probably has a getter and setter associated with it. As @Bakuriu mentioned, the attribute `=` can be overloaded. Take a look at this url to find out more - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898711/django-model-fields-getter-setter

Comment: @Bakuriu Could you please take a look at the code in my question? I just updated it a bit, because I was actually talking about the `x.attributes = something` form. Just didn't understand the concept right.